# LINQ To SQL Connection String Format when connecting over network

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a network of PCs.

I have installed the SQL server on the main PC and am installing a client c# app on another PC.

I have developed the APP with a SQL server installed on the same PC, using the following connection string:

```
"Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeadSystem;Integrated Security=True"
```

The name of the other PC on the network, where the SQL Server is "ADMIN-PC".

The SQL server instance on this PC is "ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS".

It uses windows authentication only.

How should I change the connection string? I have tried several variations but something like this would be right (I think):

```
"Data Source=\\ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeadSystem;Integrated Security=True; User ID=User; Passowrd=9381299q; providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"
```

The ADMIN-PC and the client PC are on the same network (I can see the ADMIN PC in my network on the client PC and have accessed the admin pc from the client pc for file-sharing).

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: there is a site called [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) look for the Sql Express example

Comment: The main thing to check is if the SQL server is configured to accept remote tcp/ip connections, SQLExpress is not by default.

Comment: Try this: Server=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LeadSystem;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
If its not working, you should try to connect with the SQL Management Studio to check if all ports are open and the sql server is configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't prefix the location with the double-backslash.

If you want to use integrated security don't specify a username and password.

> Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeadSystem;Integrated Security=True; providerName=System.Data.SqlClient